# How can I make a variable that php will parse?

Tags: php, variables

Is there any way in php to define a variable like...

```
$content = if ($user['adminLevel'] > 0) echo '<p>YAY IT WORKS</p>';
```

And when you echo the variable it will perform the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just writing a function? Then instead of "echoing the variable", just call the function.

```
function content() {
    global $user;
    if ($user['adminLevel'] > 0) {
        echo '<p>YAY IT WORKS</p>';
    }
}


// and then later on...
content();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a ternary operator

```
$content = $user['adminLevel'] > 0 ? '<p>YAY IT WORKS</p>' : null;
echo $content;
```

This works like the following

```
$var = condition ? 'true value' : 'false value';
```

http://tuxradar.com/practicalphp/3/12/4

Comment: A ternary operator is probably the closest you'll get without doing some sort of eval type operation.  It is SLIGHTLY different than what the user wanted in that the condition is checked on being assigned to $content not when the echo is done (it shouldn't be a problem but it might cause issues if the poster thinks it's done the other way).

Comment: This is probably the simplest solution if you will be using it in one place. It didn't even cross my mind. But if you will be using the same code in lots of different places then a function would be easier when it comes to updating.

Comment: You could always echo on the assignment, but I think assignments and print statements shouldn't be on the same line IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible, but you could create a function.

```
function adminLevel($user) {
    if($user['adminLevel'] > 0) {
        return '<p>YAY IT WORKS!</p>';
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

then you just call it in your php.

```
$content = adminLevel($user);
```